# iOS animating with custom route

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, transformation

I have a method  which transforms some subviews of my view in a very specific route. so this method has one CGFloat parameter which varies between 0.0f and 1.0f.

I want to know which is the best way to animate this transformations (say it will begin at transform:0.0f and end at transform:1.0f). Obviously UIView's animateWithDuration won't work because I want my subviews to move exactly as I want.

Should I write my own custom interval based animation function to do this? (I dont want to to be honest). Or is there a simple way ?

Comment: Are animating along a path? Can you describe the animation in greater detail.

Comment: @Rob I'm not sure if i'll be able to describe the transformations precisely. I'll try to explain. There's this method transform:(CGFloat)fraction which transforms 4 views in 3d. So, the starting point is when fraction=0.0f, and the ending point is at 1.0f.
But between 0.0f and 1.0f the paths of transformation change several times, that is the reason I can't use UIView animateWithDuration.

Comment: So I guess I could use NSTimer and call the method with with an acceleration curve, I was wondering if there is another way.

Comment: Yes, you could use a `NSTimer` or a `CADisplayLink`, but when I hear that the "paths of transformation change several times", I think `CAKeyframeAnimation`, there you can identify some key points in the overall animation. It's hard for me to say without better understanding what you're doing, but hopefully you can dig around for `CAKeyframeAnimation` or perhaps `Core Animation`, more generally, and maybe you'll find something that suits your purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested I used this class called [CPAccelerationTimer](https://github.com/yangmeyer/CPAccelerationTimer) which did the trick.
It basically is an NSTimer with custom acceleration

Answer (score 0):

use this `[UIView animateWithDuration:`

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:<> delay:<> options:<> animations:^{
                         <animation code 1>
} completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         <code for after animatop>
                     }];
```

like this

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:<> delay:<> options:<> animations:^{
                         <animation code 1>
} completion:^(BOOL finished){
[UIView animateWithDuration:<> delay:<> options:<> animations:^{
                         <animation code 1>
} completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         <code for after animatop>
                     }];
                     }];
```

Comment: Well yes I coud break the function into smaller functions, and call them one by one. But I'm not into that at all , because I want to be able to set an acceleration curve for the whole thing.
What I want is more something like an NSTimer with a custom acceleration curve, which will call my method. I want to know if I should write this myself, or is there an existing way?